# Irrelevant content in java compilation

Tags: java

Can someone be so kind to let me know why the heck javac is printing extra lines with zeros when executed the following lines of code? I have intentionally printed the number of possible lines in the first line, which is exactly equal to the number of nonzero lines. Any advice?
Code:

```
int[] fa = new int[15];
    int[][] sa = new int[100][3];
    int a=0, b=0;

    for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
        fa[i] = i+1;
    }


    for(int i=0; i<fa.length; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<fa.length; j++){
            for(int k=j+1; k<fa.length; k++){
                if(fa[i]+fa[j]+fa[k]==15){
                    sa[a][0] = fa[i];
                    sa[a][1] = fa[j];
                    sa[a][2] = fa[k];
                    a++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(a);
    for(int i=0; i<sa.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            System.out.print(sa[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

The output:

> ```
> 12
> 1 2 12 
> 1 3 11 
> 1 4 10 
> 1 5 9 
> 1 6 8 
> 2 3 10 
> 2 4 9 
> 2 5 8 
> 2 6 7 
> 3 4 8 
> 3 5 7 
> 4 5 6 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0
> ```

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem; you should work on your variable naming, it feels like i'm reading decompiled code.

Comment: @Mritunjay: it is picking the subsets of 3 numbers of `fa` that sums 15, and collecting those subsets in `sa`.

Comment: @ug_ sorry, my comment was for Mritunjay. Will edit :)

Comment: @Aba74, Did it work?

Comment: @Aba74, review and accept your most suitable answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: Clarifying.. the program output isn't from _compilation_, but rather from _running_ the code in the JVM (using `java`).

Answer (score 3):

To print you are iterating on `sa`:

```
for(int i=0; i<sa.length; i++){
```

And at the beginning you stated it has 100 rows (**default values to 0**):

```
int[][] sa = new int[100][3];
```

It shows those 100 rows independently of what you did on your second `for` with `fa`.

Try with:

```
for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
        System.out.print(sa[i][j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the content of the entire `sa` regardless of how many items you have added to it. The first 12 items print correctly, while the remaining items print the initial values of `int[3]` arrays, which happen to be zeros.

You can fix this by iterating up to `a` items, like this:

```
for(int i=0; i < a; i++) {
//              ^^^ 
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
        System.out.print(sa[i][j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Alternatively, you could switch to using lists in place of arrays. Since lists grow dynamically, you would be able to avoid this problem altogether:

```
class Triple {
    private final a, b, c;
    public Triple(int a, int b, int c) {this.a=a; this.b=b; this.c=c;}
    public int getA() { return a; }
    public int getB() { return b; }
    public int getC() { return c; }
}

List<Triple> sa = new ArrayList<>();
...
if(fa[i]+fa[j]+fa[k]==15){
    sa.add(new Triple(fa[i], fa[j], fa[k]));
}
...
for (Triple t : sa) {
    ...
}
```